# Copying styles in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, style

I'm using the **Count points in polygon** tool to estimate points and make some time-series in *QGIS 2.18.4*. I edit shapefile of points (just delete rest) to make a certain date range.
As example:
1) 1995-2015
[image]
But in order to see the difference I must copy (*Right click on layer* - *Styles* - *Copy*) the styles from 1) to

2) 1975-1995.
[image]
[image]
Attribute table number of points has the same name. What can cause such a result? I tried to use different shapefiles from [GADM](http://www.gadm.org) and [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a categorized renderer is used on the first layer. Most certainly, the second does not contain the exact same category values. That's why you don't see anything. Use a graduated renderer instead!

Comment: Very good catch!